# Downloaded excel file gets corrupted in export to excel functionality

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I am writing export to excel functionality in mvc. Controller CreateExcelDocument method returns actionresult but my downloaded file gets corrupted.

```
 public ActionResult CreateExcelDocument(DataSet dataSet)  
        {
            byte[] data;

            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (SpreadsheetDocument workbook = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(memoryStream, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook, true))
                {
                    WriteToExcelFile(dataSet, workbook);
                }

                memoryStream.Flush();
                memoryStream.Position = 0;

                data = new byte[memoryStream.Length];
                memoryStream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
            }

            return File(data, "application/ms-excel", "Report.xlsx");
        }
```

My ajax success function written like below:

```
success: function (response) { 
                var blob = new Blob([response], {type: 'application/ms-excel' });
                var downloadUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                var a = document.createElement("a");
                a.href = downloadUrl;
                a.download = 'Report.xlsx';
                document.body.appendChild(a);
                a.click();
}
```

File getting downloaded but it getting corrupted when try to open the downloaded file. Could anyone help me with the above code.

Comment: You're using the wrong content type to begin with. `application/ms-excel` refers to the obsolete `xls` format replaced by `xlsx`. The correct one is `application/vnd.ms-excel`

Comment: What is `SpreadsheetDocument`? Which library are you using and what does `WriteToExcelFile` do? Have you tried just saving the file locally and trying to open it? If `WriteToExcelFile` creates a bad file you won't be able to open it on the client side.

Comment: Are you using the OpenXML SDK directly? That's very low level and easy to get wrong. A better idea is to use a library like EPPlus, NPOI, ClosedXML or others to generate the file. With eg EPPlus loading a DataTable into a sheet is as simple as `sheet.Cells.LoadFromDataTable(table)`. There's `LoadFromCollection` and `LoadFromDataReader` too. The methods can create a table with headers and a predefined table style, all with a single call

Comment: ClosedXML is as easy to use `wb.Worksheets.Add(dataTable);` is enough to add a DataTable

Comment: What if you do `data = memoryStream.ToArray()` instead?

Comment: WriteToExcelFile just adding the dataset to excel file by creating the object of Workbook. And yes i am using OpenXML SDK.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos
 How to call the controller method from jquery ajax in case if we use ClosedXML.

Comment: Same as any other HTTP endpoint. The code you use in your MVC actions doesn't affect how clients call those actions

Comment: `WriteToExcelFile just adding the dataset to excel file` and if that has a bug, the resulting file will be corrupt. Have you tried saving that file to disk and opening it? Changing the MVC code won't fix bugs in `WriteToExcelFile`

Comment: @Magnus this shouldn't matter. In fact [the source code](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/io/memorystream.cs#L550) shows `ToArray()` does almost the same thing as `Read` in this case

Comment: public ActionResult WriteToExcelFile(DataSet dataSet)
        {
            using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
            {
                //Add DataTable in worksheet  
                wb.Worksheets.Add(dataSet);
                using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    wb.SaveAs(stream);
                    //Return xlsx Excel File  
                    return File(stream.ToArray(), "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "Report.xlsx");
                }
            }

        }

Comment: i have changed the code to use ClosedXML but still the downloaded file getting corrupted. i am returning actionresult from the mvc method, i think the problem is with the ajax success method.

Comment: how to map the response in ajax success method.